# Executing a stored procedure with mssql_exec differs from mssql_query

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm really mesmerized by this problem and I'm wondering if someone already stumbled upon something like this. Here is the situation :

I'm building a website (PHP) that needs to connect to a distant Microsoft SQL Server instance to execute stored procedures. The distant server is accessed through a VPN (SSL). For this part, everything works fine.

The problem is when I try to execute one particular stored procedure, the process differs when I execute it with mssql_query VS mssql_execute. The procedure basically calculates data and creates a new item to insert into the items table. When I create a query string shaped like this :

```
EXEC XXXXXXXXXX @param1 = value, @param2 = value2
```

it works fine. When I execute the same procedure with mssql_init, mssql_bind and mssql_exec, I get this error :

```
CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'XXXXXXXXXX'.
```

Unfortunately, I don't have enough rights on the MSSQL Instance to change permissions by myself. For security purposes the administrators try to restrict permissions to the minimum required to run the website.

Before asking them for create table on the entire database, I want to make sure this isn't a known problem with the PHP MSSQL library.

Here are the specs of what I'm currently using :

- PHP 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.6
- Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu)
- mssql PHP extension
- OpenConnect version v5.01

PS: I've setup my FreeTDS with a configuration that looks like this :

```
[XXXXXXX]
host = XX.XX.XX.XX
port = 1433
tds version = 8.0
client charset = UTF-8
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: For people who stumbles on something similar, it looked like my problem was caused by a permission bug on the MSSQL Server. The db admin changed me to db owner for test purposes. After successfull tests he then put me back to my schema (a custom one) and now it works. Kinda weird...

Answer (score 0):

What should happend here is that if you exec, you need to first connect to the server and give your credentials. I think they are different that the ones used by mssql_exec. You need a way to specify the same credentials